# Spring KafkaListener disconnects and discontinues consuming - CommitFailedException

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I have a Kafka topic that never purges messages (intentionally).  I want to continually consume messages from it, even if my consumer goes offline for days/weeks/months.  By my understanding, this may not be possible, so I'm starting small with my solution.

While running it, I get the following exception, after which my @KafkaListener never seems to consume messages again even though new messages are being put onto "topic1" all the time.  I have tried restarting my Spring Boot app.  I have even tried resetting the group offset back to 0 with:

```
kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --group aggregator-txnstokafka-group-ethereum --topic topic1 --reset-offsets --to-earliest --execute
```

But consumption never resumes.

**How do I get my @KafkaListener to resume consuming messages?**

Exception:

```
2023-10-05 11:14:31,755 ERROR org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory [aggregator-txnstokafka-listener-ethereum-0-C-1] - commitTransaction failed: CloseSafeProducer [delegate=org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer@7de7fc0]
org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Cannot execute transactional method because we are in an error state
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.TransactionManager.maybeFailWithError(TransactionManager.java:1125)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.TransactionManager.lambda$beginCommit$2(TransactionManager.java:373)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.TransactionManager.handleCachedTransactionRequestResult(TransactionManager.java:1231)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.TransactionManager.beginCommit(TransactionManager.java:372)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.commitTransaction(KafkaProducer.java:755)
        at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory$CloseSafeProducer.commitTransaction(DefaultKafkaProducerFactory.java:1156)
        at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaResourceHolder.commit(KafkaResourceHolder.java:58)
        at org.springframework.kafka.transaction.KafkaTransactionManager.doCommit(KafkaTransactionManager.java:186)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:743)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:711)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:152)
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeInTransaction(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2387)
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeRecordListenerInTx(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2353)
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2329)
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2003)
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeIfHaveRecords(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1373)
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1364)
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1255)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.CommitFailedException: Transaction offset Commit failed due to consumer group metadata mismatch: The coordinator is not aware of this member.
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.TransactionManager$TxnOffsetCommitHandler.handleResponse(TransactionManager.java:1771)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.TransactionManager$TxnRequestHandler.onComplete(TransactionManager.java:1322)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientResponse.onComplete(ClientResponse.java:109)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.completeResponses(NetworkClient.java:583)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:575)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.maybeSendAndPollTransactionalRequest(Sender.java:418)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.runOnce(Sender.java:316)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:243)
        ... 1 more
2023-10-05 11:14:31,760 ERROR org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer [aggregator-txnstokafka-listener-ethereum-0-C-1] - Transaction rolled back
org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Cannot execute transactional method because we are in an error state
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.TransactionManager.maybeFailWithError(TransactionManager.java:1125)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.TransactionManager.lambda$beginCommit$2(TransactionManager.java:373)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.TransactionManager.handleCachedTransactionRequestResult(TransactionManager.java:1231)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.TransactionManager.beginCommit(TransactionManager.java:372)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.commitTransaction(KafkaProducer.java:755)
        at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory$CloseSafeProducer.commitTransaction(DefaultKafkaProducerFactory.java:1156)
        at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaResourceHolder.commit(KafkaResourceHolder.java:58)
        at org.springframework.kafka.transaction.KafkaTransactionManager.doCommit(KafkaTransactionManager.java:186)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:743)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:711)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:152)
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeInTransaction(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2387)
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeRecordListenerInTx(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2353)
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2329)
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2003)
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeIfHaveRecords(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1373)
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1364)
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1255)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.CommitFailedException: Transaction offset Commit failed due to consumer group metadata mismatch: The coordinator is not aware of this member.
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.TransactionManager$TxnOffsetCommitHandler.handleResponse(TransactionManager.java:1771)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.TransactionManager$TxnRequestHandler.onComplete(TransactionManager.java:1322)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientResponse.onComplete(ClientResponse.java:109)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.completeResponses(NetworkClient.java:583)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:575)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.maybeSendAndPollTransactionalRequest(Sender.java:418)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.runOnce(Sender.java:316)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:243)
        ... 1 more
```

On the server, I configured:

```
offsets.retention.minutes=5256000
group.max.session.timeout.ms=2147483647
```

In my client, I configured

```
session.timeout.ms=2147483646
max.poll.interval.ms=900000
```

Here is a snippet of the code which pulls from topic1 and publishes to topic2 (the rest of the functionality is stripped for brevity here).

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("evmBlockToKakfaTemplate")
KafkaTemplate<Number, Object> destTemplate;

@KafkaListener(id = "aggregator-txnstokafka-listener-ethereum", groupId = "aggregator-txnstokafka-group-ethereum", topics = "topic1", containerFactory = "evmTxnsToKafkaContainerFactory")
public void onMessage(ConsumerRecord<Long, String> record, Acknowledgment acknowledgement) {
  // Do some stuff
  destTemplate.send("topic2", key, value);
}

@Bean
public KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String>> evmTxnsToKafkaContainerFactory(
        KafkaTransactionManager<Number, Object> evmTxnAggregatorTransactionManager,
        ConsumerFactory<? super String, ? super String> evmTxnToKakfaConsumerFactory) {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.getContainerProperties().setTransactionManager(evmTxnAggregatorTransactionManager);
    factory.setConsumerFactory(evmTxnToKakfaConsumerFactory);
    factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE);
    factory.setCommonErrorHandler(new TransactionAggregatorErrorHandler());
    factory.setConcurrency(1);
    factory.setBatchListener(false);

    return factory;
}

@Bean
public KafkaTemplate<Number, Object> evmTxnToKakfaTemplate() {
    return new KafkaTemplate<Number, Object>(evmTxnToKakfaProducerFactory());
}

@Bean
public DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<Number, Object> evmTxnToKakfaProducerFactory() {
    Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<>();
    config.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, destKafkaBroker);
    config.put(ProducerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, "aggregator-txnstokafka-" + chain);
    config.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, LongSerializer.class.getName());
    config.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class.getName());
    config.put(ProducerConfig.ENABLE_IDEMPOTENCE_CONFIG, true);
    config.put(ProducerConfig.TRANSACTIONAL_ID_CONFIG, "aggregator-txnstokafka-" + chain + "-");
    return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(config);
}

@Bean
public ConsumerFactory<? super String, ? super BlockchainDataAggregator> evmTxnToKakfaConsumerFactory() {
    Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<>();
    config.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, srcKafkaBroker);
    config.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, LongDeserializer.class.getName());
    config.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonDeserializer.class.getName());
    config.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, "false");
    config.put(ConsumerConfig.ISOLATION_LEVEL_CONFIG, IsolationLevel.READ_COMMITTED.toString().toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT));
    config.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
    config.put(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, "2147483646"); // Integer max value. About 24.8 days
    //config.put(ConsumerConfig.HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, ...);
    config.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, "900000"); // 15 minutes
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(config);
}

@Bean
KafkaTransactionManager<Number, Object> evmTxnAggregatorTransactionManager(
        DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<Number, Object> evmTxnToKakfaProducerFactory) {
    KafkaTransactionManager<Number, Object> kafkaTransactionManager = new KafkaTransactionManager<>(
            evmTxnToKakfaProducerFactory);
    kafkaTransactionManager
            .setTransactionSynchronization(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.SYNCHRONIZATION_ALWAYS);
    return kafkaTransactionManager;
}
```

We use...

- Kafka 2.12-3.2.0 on Ubuntu
- Java 18
- Spring Boot Starter 2.7.4 with Spring Kafka
- "topic1" is 1 partition with 3 replicants (intentionally)

Answer (score 0):

Little confused about the requirements here. However, you can check couple of things.

1. What is the retention bytes given for that topic
2. As you are resetting your consumer to the earliest, kindly try to change the consumer group name and see if the issue persists. This commit failed exception can happen if you are trying to access an invalid offset.

Comment: 1) retention.ms=-1  (topic is never purged)
2) I'd like to use the same consumer group name.  Changing it every time this happens would require a new build/release of the code.

I have over a million messages on this topic1 (and others like it), and some consumers die after 200,000+ messages, others after 10,000+ messages, others have not died and are still consuming messages.  So the failure is erratic, but in all cases I can never resume consumption (so I delete "topic2" and start all over).

Comment: Can you confirm why you are using the transactions here? Are you trying to establish Exactly-Once semantics here, which is CPP (Consume from Topic 1 and Process the message and Produce it to Topic 2).

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  I want to perform Exactly-Once semantics to get every message from Topic 1, do some stuff with it, then publish it to Topic 2.  I also update a database (in a non-XA way sadly), so I chose not to use KStreams.  But, yes, I'd like to consume exactly once and publish exactly once and do those 2 operations together or not at all.

Comment: Okies. It appears the issue is on the consumer commit offset side and the consumer getting kicked out of the consumer group under a specific circumstance. Would you mind referring this demo project from the community on the exactly once semantics. https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/examples/src/main/java/kafka/examples/ExactlyOnceMessageProcessor.java

Comment: thank you.  I'll try that out.